# Check filesize before upload

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, client-side, html4

I have a website that allows users to upload video files but I want to limit the filesize to 2MB , this is pretty straightforward after uploading the file but does anyone knows if I can check the file-size **before** uploading it so I don't overload the server unnecessarily ?

I might be looking for a javascript/ajax solution but I don't have a clue on how to achieve this.

Any help will be very welcome. Thanks guys!

**UPDATE:**

I need to check the file size on **client-side** and NOT on **server-side**, is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read local files in JavaScript using `file reader` in HTML5:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    console.log(f.size);        /*<--Here is your size of the file! :D*/
  }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: Dear Derek, thank you so much for your solution, it seems very interesting and I'll keep it for future use, but do you know how to achieve this in html4 ?

Comment: @Tuga, I don't think it is possible in HTML4. You have to do this in the sever.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep searching for a solution in html4.

Comment: @Tuga, actually you can use Flash to do that.

Answer (score -2):

If you use php you can set php option - 'upload_max_filesize'. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize May be it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to "**check the file-size before uploading it so I don't overload the server unnecessarily**", basically, I need to check the file size on the **client-side** and **NOT** on **server-side**.