# How do you configure a MultipartResolver for different maxUploadSize for a video size o an picture size?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, upload, multipart

i'd like define a **MultipartResolver** for video file and other for picture file but different size.

```
<!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
 <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
 <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000"/>        
</beans:bean>
```

any idea?

a solution is to validate file after upload with a **spring validator**, but the file has been uploaded ...

Comment: In the same form you are allowing image and video uploading ??

Comment: it`s for api method implementation

Comment: What I intend to ask is that , is the same method handling both types of uploads or each upload have it's own method.??

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can happen is that you can check the size of the file at client side using Javascript (If you are using HTML5), before the file go to server.

[HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133870/check-filesize-before-upload) has feature to check the file size

Comment: thanks, but my question need using spring without javascript validation

Comment: I see, Spring is server side technology and how come you know the size of the file before the resource reach to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following
Take an example, for video file max size = 1000 and for picture files max size = 500

Then in multipartResolver bean define highest value as 1000 for "maxUploadSize" attribute.
So for Video as well as for picture Spring will check max size limit as 1000 first.

Then you need to write customize code to validate picture file to allow max size upto 500.
check sample code at 
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-fileupload-example.html

or

check for some method like mr.setMaxUploadSize(10000); using which you can set max size at runtime to multipartResolver  bean.

Comment: thanks, but i'd like to check maxsize by multipartResolver. This solution should validate into controller spring

Answer (score 0):

I can offer to use some composite implementation of interface MultipartResolver which takes list of MultipartResolver and you can define what MultipartResolver use based on some identification of incoming requests.