# Restrict image upload file size

Tags: php, upload, limit

currently i have php validation as follows

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5120) 
{
$_SESSION['error'] = 'Upload FAILED, file is too large !';
header("Location: upload.php");
exit;
}
```

But this does not seem to stop any large files being uploaded! any help much appreciated!!

Comment: I think that the filesize is only checked after the upload. So what might be happening is that the file is uploaded, it's too large, so the user sees the error. But the file is there on the server by that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to restrict the upload file size :

```
$max_size = /* whatever */; //File Size in Bytes

if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_size) {
      die('The file you uploaded is too large.');
    }
```

Comment: Note: this won't prevent the file from being uploaded. The user still has to wait for the whole thing to transfer, and you incur the bandwidth usage involved.

Comment: thank you for your reply, how would i check the size of the file and prevent it being uploaded?

Comment: @ceejayoz Adding it as a additional info to my answer, permission please :)

Comment: @neeko use javascript...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133870/check-filesize-before-upload

Comment: @Mr.Alien how do i implement the javascript?

Comment: pass an id to your element, and retrieve the info else use this jQuery solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/find-out-file-size-before-uploading-using-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Use `upload_max_filesize`

Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize